# JOIN when row doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (budget, transactions and categories).

Transactions can be categorised with a category_id (which links to the categories table where the category_name is store).

I'm selecting the transactions for a certain month and I need to join the category_id in the transactions table to the category_id in the categories table in order to get the category name for the transaction).

The problem is that some months don't have spending in a particular category, so when I join – it just doesn't select these transactions, but I'd still like to show them as 0 if the category isn't present for any transactions for that month (because it needs to be displayed on the UI as £0 of budget spent for that month).

I've tried using outer, left, outer left joins on the transactions > budgets join but I'm still not able to select the transactions if the category_id doesn't exist.

```
select budget_id, category_name, total, sum(amount) as spent, total - sum(amount) as available, period 

from budgets

inner join categories on budgets.category_id = categories.category_id 
inner join transactions on budgets.category_id = transactions.category_id

where month(date) = month("2019-01-15") and budgets.account_id = 5 
group by budget_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
select budget_id, category_name, total, sum(amount) as spent, total - sum(amount) as available, period,transactions.* 

from budgets

left join categories on budgets.category_id = categories.category_id 
left join transactions on transactions.category_id = budgets.category_id
group by budget_id
```

Comment: It doesn't I'm afraid, if the category_id is set to null in the transactions table, it won't select it.

Comment: I edited my answer try this without "where month(date) = month("2019-01-15") and budgets.account_id = 5" .